# Naïve optimization by stepping until the error falls below a threshold

Tags: haskell, recursion

As an exercise, I wanted to rewrite this toy Python code in Haskell:

```
def f(x):
    return abs(42-x)**2

def improve(x):
    newX = x + 0.1
    return newX, f(newX)

def optimize(f, goal):
    x = 0
    err = f(x)
    while not err < goal:
        x, err = improve(x)
    return x, err

print(optimize(f, 0.5))
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/OPYig7)

My solution works but is quite ugly:

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a
f x = abs(42-x)^2

improve :: (Fractional a) => (a -> b) -> a -> (a, b)
improve f x =
    let newX = x+0.1
    in (newX, f newX)

step :: (Fractional a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> b -> a -> (a, b)
step f goal x =
    let
        newX = x+0.1
        err = f newX
    in
        if err < goal then (newX, err) else step f goal newX

optimize :: (Fractional a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> b -> (a, b)
optimize f goal = step f goal 0

main :: IO ()
main = print $ optimize f 0.5
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/lAheSR)

I am trying to find a solution without explicit recursion using a fold or something, but did not have an idea yet on how to do it. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guys at #haskell pointed me to [until](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/until_f.html). This makes it satisfactory to me.

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f x = abs(42-x)^2

improve :: Fractional b => (b -> c) -> (b, a) -> (b, c)
improve f (x, _) = (newX, f newX) where newX = x+0.1

optimize:: (Ord a, Fractional b) => (b -> a) -> a -> b -> (b, a)
optimize f goal x = until isDone (improve f) (0, f x)
    where isDone (_, err) = err < goal

main :: IO ()
main = print $ optimize f 0.5 0
```

http://ideone.com/ZlC7x8